Is there a way to calculate leverage of an XGBregressor and LGBRegressor Model that have categorical enabled?
I am sorry if this is a silly question
I want to plot a standardised residuals vs leverage graph and I want to know how to calculate/get the leverage so I can plot the graph? Is there a way to do this for both these models without having to encode the variables?

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.
